# Xtext cannot read javax.persistence.ManyTo*, OneTo* FetchType properly

Tags: xtext, hibernate-annotations

I'm currently searching for a problem in one of our projects, which uses Xtext to generate java source code.
We use the model inferrer and Xannotation to use javax.* annotations to generate our entities.

```
import javax.persistence.FetchType
import javax.persistence.Id 
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne

package test.some.namespace {
    domain DomainA {
        entity for table "DOMAINA" {
            @Id 
            @Column(name = "DAIA", unique = true)
            Long id;
        }
    }
    domain DomainB {
        entity for table "DOMAINB" {
            @Id 
            @Column(name = "DAIB", unique = true) 
            Long id;

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType::LAZY)
            DomainA domainA;
        }
    }
    domain DomainC {
        entity for table "DOMAINC" {
            @Id
            @Column(name = "DAIC", unique = true)
            Long id;

            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType::LAZY)
            DomainA domainA;
        }
    }
}
```

We search for the annotation by iterating through `XAnnotationElementValuePair pair : annotation.getElementValuePairs()` and return the value `pair.getValue()`, so far it works.

Now we try to access the FetchType with `(exp as XMemberFeatureCall).feature` where `exp` is the result of `pair.getValue()`.

For `DomainB.domainA` it will return an instance of `org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.impl.JvmEnumerationLiteralImplCustom`.

For `DomainC.domainA` it will return an instance of `org.eclipse.xtext.common.types.impl.JvmVoidImplCustom`.

This problem only occurs when I save the document. This is the current thread stack from eclipse.

```
Thread [Worker-5] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 60 in CustomDSLJvmModelInferrer$2))    
    owns: ClusteringBuilderState  (id=19135)    
    CustomDSLJvmModelInferrer.xtend line: 60    
    JvmDispatchableModelAssociator.installDerivedState(DerivedStateAwareResource, boolean) line: 66 
    BatchLinkableResource(DerivedStateAwareResource).installDerivedState(boolean) line: 159 
    DerivedStateAwareResourceDescriptionManager.internalGetResourceDescription(Resource, IDefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy) line: 53  
    DefaultResourceDescriptionManager$1.get() line: 60  
    DefaultResourceDescriptionManager$1.get() line: 1   
    OnChangeEvictingCache.get(Object, Resource, Provider<T>) line: 75   
    DerivedStateAwareResourceDescriptionManager(DefaultResourceDescriptionManager).getResourceDescription(Resource) line: 58    
    ClusteringBuilderState.writeNewResourceDescriptions(BuildData, IResourceDescriptions, CurrentDescriptions, IProgressMonitor) line: 366  
    ClusteringBuilderState.doUpdate(BuildData, ResourceDescriptionsData, IProgressMonitor) line: 121    
    ClusteringBuilderState(AbstractBuilderState).update(BuildData, IProgressMonitor) line: 112  
    XtextBuilder.doBuild(ToBeBuilt, IProgressMonitor, IXtextBuilderParticipant$BuildType) line: 194 
    XtextBuilder.incrementalBuild(IResourceDelta, IProgressMonitor) line: 171   
    XtextBuilder.build(int, Map, IProgressMonitor) line: 99 
    BuildManager$2.run() line: 734  
    SafeRunner.run(ISafeRunnable) line: 42  
    BuildManager.basicBuild(int, IncrementalProjectBuilder, Map<String,String>, MultiStatus, IProgressMonitor) line: 206    
    BuildManager.basicBuild(IBuildConfiguration, int, IBuildContext, ICommand[], MultiStatus, IProgressMonitor) line: 246   
    BuildManager$1.run() line: 299  
    SafeRunner.run(ISafeRunnable) line: 42  
    BuildManager.basicBuild(IBuildConfiguration, int, IBuildContext, MultiStatus, IProgressMonitor) line: 302   
    BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(IBuildConfiguration[], IBuildConfiguration[], int, MultiStatus, IProgressMonitor) line: 358 
    BuildManager.build(IBuildConfiguration[], IBuildConfiguration[], int, IProgressMonitor) line: 381   
    AutoBuildJob.doBuild(IProgressMonitor) line: 143    
    AutoBuildJob.run(IProgressMonitor) line: 241    
    Worker.run() line: 54
```

But it works fine if I just modify the document without saving. Stack from eclipse:

```
Thread [Worker-3] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 60 in CustomDSLJvmModelInferrer$2))    
    owns: DirtyStateManager  (id=19093) 
    owns: Object  (id=19094)    
    CustomDSLJvmModelInferrer.xtend line: 60    
    JvmDispatchableModelAssociator.installDerivedState(DerivedStateAwareResource, boolean) line: 66 
    BatchLinkableResource(DerivedStateAwareResource).installDerivedState(boolean) line: 159 
    DirtyStateResourceDescription$Manager.getResourceDescription(Resource) line: 65 
    DirtyStateEditorSupport.announceDirtyState(XtextResource) line: 467 
    XtextDocumentReconcileStrategy.postParse(XtextResource, IProgressMonitor) line: 160 
    XtextDocumentReconcileStrategy.doReconcile(IRegion) line: 146   
    XtextDocumentReconcileStrategy.reconcile(IRegion) line: 65  
    XtextReconciler.doRun(XtextResource, IProgressMonitor) line: 401    
    XtextReconciler.access$3(XtextReconciler, XtextResource, IProgressMonitor) line: 386    
    XtextReconciler$1.process(XtextResource) line: 327  
    XtextReconciler$1.process(Object) line: 1   
    XtextReconciler$1(IUnitOfWork$Void).exec(T) line: 36    
    XtextDocument$XtextDocumentLocker.modify(IUnitOfWork<T,XtextResource>) line: 418    
    XtextDocument.internalModify(IUnitOfWork<T,XtextResource>) line: 131    
    XtextReconciler.run(IProgressMonitor) line: 324 
    Worker.run() line: 54
```

So far I am all out of ideas. Is it a bug? Is there something i missed?
I hope you guys can help me.

Best regards